# How to handle client_id and client_secret with Oauth2 and Swift 2 (iOS9)

Tags: oauth-2.0, swift2, ios9

I'm working on a social-app which has both web and mobile applications. On the Web app the whole Oauth implementation is quite clear in my head, but things get "complicated" when I try to think how I should handle things on the mobile app.

Once the user registers on the mobile app he should receive an access token using the Password Grant Type. I will need for that the **grant_type**, the **client_id**, the **client_secret**, the **username** and the **password**, but where should I store and keep the **client_id** and **client_secret**? Should they be kept on the server side or is it "safe" to have them on the mobile app? In that case would it be better to store them in the **keychain**?

Comment: Storing the client_secret & client_id is done locally. Although you can use it to store in keychains but the problem would be that everytime a request is made, the keychains would be accessed and also how would you store and access it in the first place. Other thing that you can do is in AppDelegate's didfinish method, retrieve the client_id and secret (maybe from hard coded form or form .plist file) and use it as a global variable or from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @UmarFarooque I see. Based on other API's I was also going for a "simple" hardcoded solution. I should read more about the Keychain and the advantages/disadvantages when it comes to a high amount of requests as you said. Although I could make on request at the beginning, store the variables locally and then continue. I read that `NSUserDefaults` should be used for user's preferences/settings more than app storing and data. Anyway, thank you for the answer!